# How to append the multiple columns of a data-frame to a new empty data-frame

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I'm having a dataset which contains multiple columns. I'm also having the list of columns:

```
columns_list = ['A1','A2','B1','B2']
    
        df
        
            A1 A2  B1   B2
        0   1  11  21   31
        1   2  12  22   32 
        2   3  13  23   33
        3   4  14  24   34
```

Based on the columns list, how do I transform data.Frame `df` to `new_df`, as below:

```
new_df
    
    0    1
0   1    11  
1   2    12   
2   3    13  
3   4    14  
4   21   31
5   22   32 
6   23   33
7   24   34
```

I tried to append that but I'm getting error. How to create the new data.frame. Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df[columns_list[0:2]].to_numpy())

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df[columns_list[2:]].to_numpy())

new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Hi Deven, thanks for the answer but is there any generic approach as the number of columns increases.

Comment: are you want to append every two columns?